# Jquery Setting id by loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'd like to set id by for loop.This is coffee script.

```
for boxWidth in[0..15]
  for boxLength in[0..15]
    boxWidth=String(boxWidth)
    boxLength=String(boxLength)
    boxId    =boxWidth+boxLength
    $ ->
        $('div').append("<span id="+boxId+"></span>")
```

I'm expecting span to be

```
  <span id="00"></span>
  <span id="01"></span>
  <span id="02"></span>
```

However I've gottenn

```
 <span id="1515"></span>
 <span id="1515"></span>
 <span id="1515"></span>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `$ -> expr` looks like a _function_ so this is probably a classic closure-in-loops problem

Comment: Thanks! I've searched for closure-in-loops problem and understood where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are bound on using coffeescript, have you tried this:

```
for boxWidth in[0..15]
  for boxLength in[0..15]
    boxWidth=String(boxWidth)
    boxLength=String(boxLength)
    boxId    =boxWidth+boxLength
    $('div').append("<span id="+boxId+"></span>")
```

no need to return the div during the loop.

also you might want to check out: http://js2coffee.org